# How do you implement skip logic branching efficiently in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Let's say I wanted to make an app where people would ask questions and get questions, based on their responses.

[image: Logic branching]

What's an efficient way to do that?

I get the feeling creating many View Controllers is not the way I'm supposed to do it.

[image: Many View Controllers]

I'd like to know what I should do instead, or what concept I need to become more familiar with to implement something like this.

Comment: Don’t confuse programming logic with interface structure. They are pretty much unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

When you say *"make an app where people would ask questions and get questions, based on their responses"*. you have a make a complex logic, there will be tons of If Else and lot more.

I suggest take a step back and start with something small. which doesn't require much complex logic, for eg. attached gif. simple storytelling app which ***"Show some content, answer some and get new question based on your answer"***.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myuyx.gif)

Comment: I understand programming basics like if-else conditions. I'm just not familiar with the schema used to represent text on the iOS interface. It's fine though. This link has kind of helped me conceptualize what a solution would look like. That and Matt's comment to look at this problem programmatically. https://youtu.be/tI4XS_1qMrk

Comment: Yes, programming approach could best in this case.

Comment: The youtube video is of 2013. I will try to find some latest tuts and pass you later

Comment: I appreciate that. I found a video that replicates some of the features I wanted, so I'm just going to follow along with the tutorial and learn what I need. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXbG9RS3C5A